# CSS - Centered image and text below it

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display a centered image and, below it, a centered and bordered text that has a width equal to its container. I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1 {
    text-align: center;
}
.d2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="d1">
    <img src="smiley.gif"><br>
    <div class="d2">This is some text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This works fine but, as I read, the use of `<br>` is an indication of poor semantic HTML and should be avoided. Is there a way to do this without the use of `<br>`?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox to the rescue:

```css
.d1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.d2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

img, .d2{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
    <div class="d2">This is some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The semantically correct element to use is the HTML5 `figure` element ( [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)) ) - this is a block level element and has the `figcaption` element and the `image` element contained within it.

The figcaption can be the first child (ie - before the image) or last child (after the image) and is also a block level element and can be centered with css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
figure {
    text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<figure>
   <figcaption>This is a fluffy kitten</figcaption>
   <img src="https://cdn.unifiedcommerce.com/content/product/small/30106.jpg" alt="fluffy kitten" width="100">
</figure>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `div` to enclose your image. A `div` is a block element, meaning, it will occupy 100% of the parent width. In your case, if the `img` tag is inside `div`, then all contents outside the `div` will be in the next line automatically.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.d1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.d2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    <img src="https://demo-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/sample.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="d2">This is some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Just use `margin` for the text section instead of `<br>` tag. And then for positioning both of the image and text to center, use the following property:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-flow: column;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.d1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column;
}
.d2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="d1">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg">
    <div class="d2">This is some text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```